# Get value of non-existing variables by calling a method

Tags: c#

As strange as it might sound, I want to access something that is not.

Here's an example:

```
int tempVar = myObject.myVar // myVar does not exist;
```

In reality I want the class to run a method, that would take the non-existing variable as a parameter:

```
object returningVariables(string variableName)
{
   object desiredObject; // a concrete object that I have stored somewhere in an array inside the class

   // going trough some List that contains names of all variables, when it finds it
   // return it

   return desiredObject;
}
```

I'll try to explain in a concrete example what I want to achieve and why.

I have a class that stores stats of an object: name, level, speed, size, etc.
They are supposed to be accessed trough a method `StatData getStat(string statName)`;

Stats are created trough a method `void MakeStat()`. The problem began when some stats were created in the class as public variables and accessed by other classed not trough the getStat() method.

Now that the public variables are changed, deleted or new ones added it takes some refactoring to get the app working again. And it looks bad when there are mixed calls with direct access to a public variable and a method for the same thing.

Please note, I do know how to fix my code the standard way; I am merely interested if above described technique will work.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Look at DynamicObject class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CreativeMagic what happens if `desiredObject` does not contain the `variableName`...what's supposed to be returned from `returningVariables`?

Comment: Some default variable or throwing exception. It's more abstract example, handling exception isn't a problem of this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like DynamicObject would help you here. You can override different methods for of that class for whatever is being called/accessed on that object: members, invocations, etc. Using dynamic means you won't be able to use intellisense anymore however. You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public class MyDynamicObject : DynamicObject {
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out Object result){
        if (binder.Name == "myVar"){
            result = "xyz";
            return true;
        }           

        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}

// Usage
dynamic x = new MyDynamicObject();
Console.WriteLine (x.myVar); // will output "xyz"
```

Comment: instead of declaring "dynamic x" can I use "MyClass x = new MyClass();"?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because dynamic flags to the C# compiler not to check the member/invocations on the object in question.